# Return dictionary<String,String> + CookieContainer cookies from task

Tags: c#, dictionary, cookies, async-await, httpwebrequest

I have some code That Runs a Task to return a dictionary ... but sometimes i need it to return both the dictionary and a cookiecontainer with cookies ... here's the code

```
        static public async Task<Dictionary<String,String>> login(string server, string id, string pw)
    {


        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest newRequest = GetNewRequest(server, cookies);
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary2.Add("name", id);
        dictionary2.Add("password", pw);
        dictionary2.Add("uni_url", server);
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = dictionary2;
        HttpWebResponse response = await MakeRequest(newRequest, cookies, "login", server, parameters);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            if (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Dictionary<String, String> answer = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                answer.Add("HTML", reader.ReadToEnd());
                return answer;// here i need it to return CookieContainer .
            }
        }
        Dictionary<String, String> answerFailed = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        answerFailed.Add("LoginFailed", "LoginFailed! No Internet Connection!");
        return answerFailed;
    }
```

my question : How do I return two different things from the same method?

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: Is your question "How do I return two different things from the same method?"?

Comment: exactly  "How do I return two different things from the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change method you can use `Tuple<T1,T2>` To return two values from task:

```
 static public async Task<Tuple<Dictionary<String,String>,CookieContainer>> login(string server, string id, string pw)
    {
     CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
      Dictionary<string, string> dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// create result tuple
     var result = Touple.create(dictionary2,cookies);
     return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The overload capabilities can't help you because only parameters should be different.

In these case i normally create a new class with all properties you need as output and return an instance of these classe from task. 
The overhead is minimal and is a good pattern for future espansion.